# Android programming many toggle button using in for loop

Tags: android, toggle, android-mediaplayer, togglebutton

My problem is when I click a toggle button, mp3player is playing and when I click off it is stopping. So when I try to run first time it works. But when I click second time it gives IllegalStateException and "E/MediaPlayer(1009): attachNewPlayer called in state 32" error. How can I fix this problem? Thanks .
My code is here:

public class MyButtons extends Activity {

```
private static final int[] idBtns = { R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3,
        R.id.btn4, R.id.btn5, R.id.btn6, R.id.btn7, R.id.btn8, R.id.btn9 };

String[] mpUrls = new String[idBtns.length];

ToggleButton[] mbuttons = new ToggleButton[idBtns.length];

MediaPlayer mp3player = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mybuttons);

    mp3player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    for (int i = 0; i < idBtns.length; i++) {
        final int k = i;
        mbuttons[k] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(idBtns[k]);
        mpUrls[k] = "http://www.testsite.com/def-music-"+ (k + 1) + ".mp3";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < idBtns.length; i++) {

        final int k = i;

        mbuttons[k].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

                if (on) {
                    try {
                        mp3player.setDataSource(mpUrls[k]);
                        mp3player.prepare();
                        mp3player.start();
                        mp3player.setLooping(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    if (mp3player.isPlaying()) {
                        mp3player.pause();
                        mp3player.seekTo(0);
                    }

                }// if(on)-else statement's end

            }// onClick's end
        });

    }// for loop's end

}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQZJv.png)

Answer (score 0):

setDataSource have to be called in Idle state. If you click toggle button second time, it's state must not be idle. So you should manage the state in you app using media player listenr and you should make it work accordingly. Anternatively, you can reset mediaplyer every time you start to play. But it propably provides bad user environment.
You can refer document about Valid and invalid states.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html